# How to get the Azure key vault secret URI for CI/CD deployment?

Tags: azure, uri, azure-keyvault

I'm working with Azure logic app for CI/CD deployment and I need to pass the Azure key vault secret `URI` to use in ARM template.

```
"actions": {
         "HTTP": {
         "runAfter": {},
         "type": "Http",
         "inputs": {
         "authentication": {
                      "audience": "https://vault/azure.net",
                      "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
          },
          "method": "GET",
          "queries": {
                      "api-version": "2016-10-01"
           },
           **"uri": "https://<keyvaultname.valut.azure.net/secrets/RG_Name/Secertverion"**
          }
    },
```

Anybody can help me to get the secret URI to pass as a parameter in ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following az cli command which will print the Secret Identifier :

```sh
az keyvault secret show --name %SECRET_NAME% --vault-name %KEY_VAULT_NAME% --query id --output tsv
```

Or, you can get it from the UI under the secret page => Secret Identifier:

[image]

Comment: how to store the secert uri in one parametre and pass to arm paramter file:  
                                                    
  uri : "https://<keyvaultname.valut.azure.net/secrets/RG_Name/Secertverion"